# SQL Injection Protection at the service level - for MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql

Are there any SQL injection filters for protection that work for MySQL?

This way there is an added level of protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider checking out http://www.greensql.com/ and see if it works for you.

**Highlights:**

- Stops SQL Injection attacks on web applications
- Blocks unauthorized database access with real time alerts
- Separates application database access privileges from administrator
  access
- Provides a complete event log for investigating database traffic and
  access
- Ensures successful implementation with 24/7 support

**Detailed Info:**

**Protects websites and databases from SQL injection.** GreenSQL's engine acts as a reverse proxy, filtering all traffic in and out of the database. It identifies malicious attacks by comparing every query’s structure with its signature bank of known attacks. Threatening queries never reach your database for execution.

**Controls access to sensitive information.** GreenSQL prevents information theft and to boost compliance with regulations such as PCI-DSS and SOX. GreenSQL's table-based firewall allows definition of users according to their  authority to run administrative commands, view information or delete it. Not only are users defined, but it's possible to define from which IP address queries may be submitted. User rights management allows organizations to separate user rights by function and stop internal information leaks. GreenSQL cloaks the entire database, allowing only indirect access, and gives further protection by enabling masking of specific sensitive data, hiding it from unauthorized view.

**Easy to install, use and manage.** Since GreenSQL does not encroach on the database, there is no need to make changes in database architecture. GreenSQL automatically detects the databases and applications environment, including application names, user names and user IP addresses. Once GreenSQL is installed, its firewall automatically protects the database from SQL injections. A single, easy-to-use management interface provides monitoring and management of data security in real time.

**Protects MS SQL Server and MySQL databases.** Web applications using MS SQL Server and MySQL databases will withstand malicious attacks.

**Protects databases in the Cloud.** GreenSQL protects Windows Azure SQL Database and Amazon RDS for MySQL and SQL Server.

**Protects your financial, identity and intellectual property in real time.** Data theft needs to be prevented, not just detected. A report on the theft of valuable data is of little use after the theft has already occurred. GreenSQL proactively prevents the theft from taking place and continuously protects the valuable assets stored in your databases.

**GreenSQL is fully scalable.** All features can be controlled using one easy-to-use management interface, so GreenSQL scales according to business needs. With a wealth of available installation options, GreenSQL can be configured as a dedicated solution protecting a single database, or to monitor and protect multiple databases simultaneously.

**Accelerated database performance.** GreenSQL’s patented caching mechanism goes far beyond its original goal of compensating for potential database latency. GreenSQL significantly accelerates database performance, showing the efficiency rate on the caching efficiency dashboard.

Comment: Please add some detail from the link to improve this.  Link only answers are usually closed as the link can break.